# anjlab check purchase from mainactivity

Tags: android

I have this class for billing:

```
public class billing extends Activity implements BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler {
    BillingProcessor bp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.billing);

        bp = new BillingProcessor(this, "YOUR LICENSE KEY FROM GOOGLE PLAY CONSOLE HERE", this);
```

anjlab project.

The problem is that I want to check if user has purchased my product from main activity. I'm trying it:

from my mainactivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
...
//check purchase
BillingProcessor bp = new BillingProcessor(); //cannot resolve constructor
String productId="android.test.purchased";
TransactionDetails transactionDetails = bp.getPurchaseTransactionDetails(productId);
if (transactionDetails != null) {
    //Already purchased
}
```

--

why cannot resolve constructor? what should I change to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check that whether the User has actually purchased your product then you can try -

```
bp.isPurchased("Your Product / SKU Name");
```

returns `true` if Purchased else `false`

Answer (score 0):

```
BillingProcessor bp = new BillingProcessor(); cannot be resolved, because there is no empty constructor available in **BillingProcessor class**
```

Inside BillingProcessor class There are only two public constructors available.

```
public BillingProcessor(Context context, String licenseKey, IBillingHandler handler)
    {
        this(context, licenseKey, null, handler);
    }

    public BillingProcessor(Context context, String licenseKey, String merchantId,
                            IBillingHandler handler)
    {
        this(context, licenseKey, merchantId, handler, true);
    }
```

You can look at the BillingProcessor class [here](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/anjlab/android/iab/v3/BillingProcessor.java).

Comment: thank you for your answer! and how can I know if user has purchased my product? from my main activity? it is possible?

Comment: use shared preference or database. Store the result in billing activity and get the result in the mainactivity.

Comment: uh, I'd like to get it from google. I'll try other ways, thank you!